# How to access other model fields through foreign key in Django Views

Tags: python, django

I want to query from OrderItem Model like
total_orders = OrderItem.objects.filter(product.user == request.user.id).count()
but i am getting error

**
NameError at /home
name 'product' is not defined
**

MY MODELS:

Product Model:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT, default=None)
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.FloatField()
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=False, null=True, blank=False)
    minorder = models.CharField(
        max_length=150, help_text='Minum Products that want to sell on per order', null=True, default=None, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField()

    category = models.ForeignKey(
        Categories, default=1, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Order Item Model

```
class OrderItem(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(
        Product, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    order = models.ForeignKey(
        Order, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    quantity = models.FloatField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    date_orderd = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    price = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.product)
```

My View:

```
def home(request):
total_orders = OrderItem.objects.filter(
        product.user == request.user.id).count()
    return render(request, "sellerprofile/home.html", {'total_orders': total_orders})
```

Answer (score 1):

Do:

```
total_orders = OrderItem.objects.filter(product__user=request.user).count()
```

You can look at the documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#field-lookups) about field lookups on more detail.

Comment: @zain you need to use a single `=`, you're currently calculating a boolean not passing kwargs to filter

Comment: @zain Please make sure you wrote correctly as said by Iain.